# sort files by specific content

Tags: linux, shell

i need to sort 157 annotation files that are in gff3 format

one of them are from transcriptome and other ones from genome
my purpose is to sort them into these  2 categories

i would ike to sort by the main difference character : the transcriptomes files contains "trinity" and the genomes files contains " scaffold " as keywords ,like under :

##gff-version 3
##feature-ontology http://song.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/song/ontology/sofa.obo?revision=1.269
##interproscan-version 5.51-85.0
##sequence-region scaffold1530size114558 1 630
scaffold1530size114558  .   polypeptide 1   630 .   +   .   ID=scaffold1530size114558;md5=6a2e960f92b2ccbad5284858e0e5aa60

and :

##gff-version 3
##feature-ontology http://song.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/song/ontology/sofa.obo?revision=1.269
##interproscan-version 5.51-85.0
##sequence-region TRINITY_DN67221_c1_g2_i2 1 542
TRINITY_DN67221_c1_g2_i2    .   polypeptide 1   542 .   +   .   ID=TRINITY_DN67221_c1_g2_i2;md5=e2ea1828cc04caa25aa6233aec734f88

this i why i get when i use the 'head' command

but i dont know how to sort those files
thanks for your help

Comment: I think you're mixing up terms here ... in the context of `Linux` `sort` is typically a reference to putting the content of the files in a certain order. I **think** what you're trying to achieve is categorising files based on content?  Can you please edit your question to that effect and be more specific about what you need to achieve?

Comment: i want to have one folder with transcriptomics file and an other one with genomics bevcause they are in the same folder atm

Comment: In that case my answer below does pretty much exactly what you're asking.  You will probably need to adjust the pattern for the filenames, and create the target directories with more suitable names or in a different place, but that's exactly whay my two `grep|xargs mv` combos below are doing.

Comment: thank you , i dont know what to write instead of file

Comment: what are your file's names? If there's a common pattern, use that ... if the common part is in the middle, use `*pattern*`, for instance. I can't really tell you  what to use  as you were only talking about the file's contents, not their names.

Comment: yes i got it , thank you for your help , its working well !

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, you **haven't** come back with clarification, so I'll take a wild guess, and base my *solution* on assumptions.

1. The files have a recognisable pattern, in my case they all start with `file`
2. The files are all in one directory
3. You want the categorised files to end up in two separate subdirectories

The actual work is done by these two lines:

```
grep -l TRINITY file* | xargs -n 1 -I{}   mv {} transcriptomes/
grep -l scaffold file* | xargs -n 1 -I{}   mv {} genomes/
```

Here is a transcript that shows how to achieve what I think you want:

```
$ ls
file1   file11  file13  file15  file17  file19  file20  file4  file6  file8
file10  file12  file14  file16  file18  file2   file3   file5  file7  file9
$ mkdir {transcriptomes,genomes}
$ grep -l TRINITY file*
file11
file12
file13
file14
file15
file16
file17
file18
file19
file20
$ grep -l scaffold file*
file1
file10
file2
file3
file4
file5
file6
file7
file8
file9
$ grep -l TRINITY file* | xargs -n 1 -I{}   mv {} transcriptomes/
$ grep -l scaffold file* | xargs -n 1 -I{}   mv {} genomes/
$ ls
genomes  transcriptomes
$ find
.
./genomes
./genomes/file1
./genomes/file10
./genomes/file3
./genomes/file2
./genomes/file4
./genomes/file6
./genomes/file7
./genomes/file5
./genomes/file8
./genomes/file9
./transcriptomes
./transcriptomes/file16
./transcriptomes/file12
./transcriptomes/file17
./transcriptomes/file13
./transcriptomes/file18
./transcriptomes/file11
./transcriptomes/file19
./transcriptomes/file15
./transcriptomes/file20
./transcriptomes/file14
```